# 301 / plus others , but not all urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We want to redirect most , but not all, of a website wit a 301 redirect.
Will this work or is the first line to much ?

```
redirect 301 / http://designers-floor.nl/
redirect 301 /index.php http://designers-floor.nl/
redirect 301 /index.php/woonbeton http://designers-floor.nl/inspiratie/
```

Comment: If that's meant to be some configuration for something that's performing the redirects, you might want to mention *what* software that's meant to be configuration for.

Comment: redirect via .htaccess  in Apache

Answer (score 0):

The `Redirect` directive will redirect any url **starting with the first fragment** to the second fragment. The first directive will thus redirect the entire site. ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect))

I recommend testing with temporary redirects until you have accomplished what you want, because testing with permanent redirects will cause those redirects to be cached. Once everything works as expected you can make the redirects permanent. Make sure that the most specific url is always listed first, so that it is matched first.

If you cannot accomplish your goal with just the `Redirect` directives, you can either use `RedirectMatch` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)) or the RewriteEngine of mod_rewrite ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)).